# How much voltage multiplication can boost converter produce?

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, inverter, boost

I want to make a PWM based inverter for my college project to convert 12V DC to 220V AC.

But as the PWM output is not exactly sine wave, it can not be stepped up using a transformer. So I need to convert 12V DC to 300V DC first, before feeding it to the H bridge for PWM.

But my question is **"Is it possible to convert 12V DC to 300V DC using a boost converter?"**

Because I have read that in commercial inverters, they first convert 12V DC to high frequency AC, step it up to 220V AC and then rectify it to get 300V DC. Why so much hassle when you can use a boost converter instead, which will be much simpler solution? Are there any technical difficulties in boost converter which prevents their use?

Also, is it possible to connect multiple boost converter available commercially in a cascade connection to get output voltage higher that what they are specified for?

Comment: There are stability issues due to the duty-cycle being too close to unity. That, and the curent through the switch would be too large. But, for low power applications, you could take this shortcut.

Comment: I'm no expert on switch-mode converters, but I don't see why 
''But as the PWM output is not exactly sine wave, it can not be stepped up using a transformer. '' 
Is supposed to be true

Comment: I presume you've never heard of a flyback converter

Comment: @JorenVaes Because feeding square wave to transformer will produce Impulse signal like voltage, as output voltage is proportional to rate of change of input.

Comment: @RupeshRoutray so, why can't you use that then? You might not get a perfect sinewave out, but you can try fixing that with filters.

Comment: @JorenVaes If I have to use bulky filters to smooth out the impulse then it will defy the purpose of using PWM to approximate a sine wave to reduce harmonics.

Comment: @RupeshRoutray a transformer's output voltage is proportional to the input voltage and not the rate of change.

Comment: You might want to look at good examples of inverter design, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Box_Challenge